# Selecting a season slice selects the seasons before and including the season slice

Tags: python-xarray

When I try to select a specific season of a dataset using .sel(season=slice('JJA')) it also selects the season before JJA - in this case DJF. I can fix the issue by calling the season number 1 or calling sel(season=slice('JJA','JJA')), but I don't understand why just saying slice('JJA') doesn't work.

```
precip=xr.open_dataset('/content/drive/MyDrive/paleoCAMPTutorials/Day2_Atmosphere/prate.sfc.mon.mean.nc')
seasonal_precip=precip.sel(time=slice('1948-1-01T00:00:00.000000000','2022-12-01T00:00:00.000000000')).groupby('time.season').mean(dim='time')
precip_test=seasonal_precip['prate'].sel(season=slice('JJA'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` either with one argument: `slice(stop)` or with 2/3 arguments: `slice(start, stop[, step])`

Calling `seasonal_precip['prate'].sel(season=slice('JJA'))` selects all seasons up to JJA, so you will get DJF and JJA.
If you just want to select JJA you can simply go with `.sel(season=slice('JJA')`